# axios causing an unintended OPTIONS request on HERE Autocomplete api

Tags: axios, here-api

I am getting a preflight error 405: Method not allowed from the HERE API when I request autocomplete as per the documentation.

## UPDATE 2:

I have since determined that Axios was adding my default.common authentication headers from my app's API client onto the HERE API client. Axios is supposed to keep those defaults separate per-client, but it seems that it doesn't ... at least not the version I have. I replaced the defaults with a per-client request interceptor and it worked fine.  The request no longer triggers an OPTION pre-flight.  No issue with HERE's API other than that it doesn't support OPTION method.

## UPDATE:

The reason it fails is because HERE does not support the OPTIONS method, only the GET.  So now the question is:  Why does axios trigger an OPTIONS request when I don't set any headers?  An XMLHttpRequest() based GET request does not trigger OPTIONS for the same URL.  Something is happening with axios but I don't know what and I can't seem to investigate the headers that axios is sending.

## ORIGINAL:

I've tried to find information about this error, as well as HTTP vs HTTPS.  I haven't seen others having this problem so I feel like I must be making a simple error.  The URL is generated correctly because it works when pasted directly into the browser for example.

```
const hereClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/'
})

async function searchHere (query) {
  let searchTerms = query.split(' ').join('+')
  let result = await hereClient.get('suggest.json', {
    params: {
      app_id: '<APPID>',
      app_code: '<APPCODE>',
      query: searchTerms
    }
  })
  return processHereSearchResults(result.data)
}
```

The GET request fails on the OPTION preflight with a 405: Method not allowed.  But if I paste the generated URL into a browser then it returns the expected results.  For example:
https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id=APPID&app_code=APPCODE&query=8131

returns:

{"suggestions":[{"label":"Česko, Brandýs nad Orlicí, 3123","language":"cs","countryCode":"CZE","locationId":"N . . .

Same result whether http or https.

Comment: Use the Network pane in browser devtools to inspect the request headers for the OPTIONS request. You’ll find an Access-Control-Allow-Headers request header. That will show you the names of the headers that your frontend code has added to the GET request and that are triggering your browser to send the OPTIONS request as part of the CORS preflight. To prevent the browser from sending that preflight OPTIONS request, you need to change your frontend code to make it not add the request headers whose names are listed in that Access-Control-Allow-Headers value.

Comment: Thanks @sideshowbarker.  I have since determined that Axios was adding my default.common authentication headers from my app's API client onto the HERE API client.  Axios is supposed to keep those defaults separate per-client, but it seems that it doesn't ... at least not the version I have.  I replaced the defaults with a per-client request interceptor and it worked fine.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have since determined that Axios was adding my default.common authentication headers from my app's API client onto the HERE API client. Axios is supposed to keep those defaults separate per-client, but it seems that it doesn't ... at least not the version I have. I replaced the default header setting with a per-client request interceptor to set my authentication and it worked fine. The request no longer triggers an OPTION pre-flight. No issue with HERE's API other than that it doesn't support OPTION method.